# When I use "flow: left" DIVs become one under second and not one after second in the same line

Tags: html, css

why in this code:

```
   <html>
   <body>
    <div style="border: 1px solid black; float: left">first div</div>
    <div style="background: red; border: 1px solid black; margin: 2px;">second div</div>
   </body>
  </html>
```

second div go under first div (you will see red in first box). Due to the all rules of the existence, second div (also it's content, but a-l-s-o it's BACKGROUND) must be from the RIGHT of first div and not under him.

Thank you for ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set both of them to float:left; 
Otherwise you may use display: inline-block; on both.

Answer (score 2):

`div` elements (and all other block level elements) take up 100% width by default.

You will have to specify a width for the elements to fit them next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them have to float:left. And, you may have to specify width.

Answer (score 0):

Non-positioned block elements **always** go on top or each other. You think of a behavior than two left floating elements have.

To achieve that, make them both floats, and give them both width as default 100% width will not do.